# Private AES-GCM key

Tags: authentication, passwords, aes, aws

I'm using Amazon's (AWS) Key Management Service (KMS) to encrypt user data, the KMS uses AES-GCM cryptography.

My problem is that as the AES-GCM key is stored in the KMS and I, *as an administrator of **my** AWS instance*, **have access to this key** and can therefore decrypt user data. My goal is to prevent that.

**What can I implement, so that even when I possess the KMS key, I cannot decrypt the user data?**

I was thinking that before the user is encrypting data locally with his key stored in KMS, he could encrypt the AES-GCM key with his password that is unknown to AES (and me as the admin). Is that a solution? What algorithms should I use? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want asymmetric encryption. One key for encryption, one for decryption.

Comment: @YorickdeWid could you explain more in a answer? I was thinking of adding a additional security layer by encrypting the AES Key again. But I am not sure if that is secure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it's not about being able to *prevent* access to the keys, as much as it is creating an environment that's able to be audited (i.e., user/admin actions are tracked / reviewed periodically).

The problem you'll run into trying to encrypt, double encrypt, triple encrypt, etc, is that *at some point*, someone will need the ability to manage (read: decrypt) the data. This could be developers working on the platform, the user needing help with something, data needing to be ported to another application, *the list goes on...*. The best thing you can do is put a system in place that provides reliable accountability for access to the keys. *Sidenote: an HSM doesn't hurt either :)*

> AWS CloudHSM provides you with a dedicated hardware device installed
> in your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) that provides a FIPS 140-2
> Level 2 validated single-tenant HSM to store and use your keys. You
> have total control over your keys and the application software that
> uses them with CloudHSM.

**Bottom Line**

Using KMS or other managed services has the benefit of great auditing / tracking -for visibility into who accessed keys (*and when*), as well as being able to rotate them on a periodic basis.

[Other KMS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the KMS IAM policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html) to limit specific AWS users or instances from encrypting or decrypting data with a specific KMS customer master key.